# WEBAPI2 performance of many vs single controller

Tags: c#, .net, performance, asp.net-web-api2

So, is it better for me to make several requests to a single WebAPI2 controller or make the same amount of requests to many controllers. i.e does a single controller handling 10 requests perform worse than 10 controllers handling one request each?

Either way could you please provide an explanation of why and how is one better than the other as well as how the request handling is different between the two.

Comment: I suspect that it makes little difference, as I think the controller is created per request, but there might be some caching issues. I would love to see a good answer

Comment: When you say 10 controllers handling one request each, are you talking about structure (i.e. 10 request methods on one controller) or activiation (i.e. singleton vs. per request resources)?

Comment: If I had say 1 controller that allowed me to get 10 different entities (I know, bad design, just as an example) I make one request for each vs putting each get request in a different controller, one for each entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly 0 difference.

Unless you explicitly change the default behaviour, a new controller instance is created for each request. So whether you create 10 instances of controller A or 10 instances of controller B makes no difference: you get 10 instances either way.

It shouldn't be said that if controller A is more expensive than controller B that this will have an effect, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

One call is better.

There are actually several factors that include this.  the major one is this, In any given system the efficiency of the system is the slowest component.  In most cases with multi-tiered architecture unless you are doing something incredibly complex in your calculations the slowest part is the between tier transfer of information.  So with multiple transmissions across the tiers say you have process a that takes 10 ms to complete and process b that takes 25 ms to complete, but your transmission takes 100 ms to go both ways, if you are doing a single threaded call you will be waiting 135 ms for a call that accomplishes both, vs 235 for multiple calls.

But wait you ask what happens if both calls are in different threads.  Ok now it is a matter of system resources, sure your standing threads would make that faster to a point.  You are still talking at best a 10 ms speed bump in the scenario described above, almost trivial when speaking on the large full transmission scale.  But what happens when your calls exceed the standing thread number, since api calls are stateless each call is handled in it's own thread.  So now you have to pay the penalty to spin up a thread, which is a very complex operation.

There are scenario's that you could do multiple api calls for the same operation, but I would recommend only using those for things that are not dependant on each other, for instance process a goes off completes comes back and goes on completely independant from process b

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the question: the OP asks whether there is a difference between 1 controller handling 10 separate requests or 10 controllers each handling a single request. It's not about grouping requests in a single call.